# Can anything be said about continuous functions whose domain is an infinite product of topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, infinite-product

Based on my readings much can be said about functions that map into the product topology, but can anything be said about functions that map *from* the product topology? Do they preserve continuity?

Comment: What does "preserve continuity" mean?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. I wonder if you're asking the following: "Suppose for each $i\in I$, $X_i, Y_i$ are topological spaces and $f_i:X_i\rightarrow Y_i$ is a continuous map. Need $$g:\prod_{i\in I}X_i\rightarrow \prod_{i\in I}Y_i: (x_i)_{i\in I}\mapsto (y_i)_{i\in I} $$ be continuous as well (with respect to the product topologies on $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ and $\prod_{i\in I}Y_i$)?" Is that in fact what you're asking, or are you asking something else?

Comment: Note that there's an asymmetry here. Forget topology for the moment, and restrict to products of *two* sets. Given functions $g_1: A\rightarrow B_1$ and $g_2: A\rightarrow B_2$, we can naturally build a map from $A$ to $B_1\times B_2$: namely, $$a\mapsto (g_1(a), g_2(a)).$$ However, there is no similar construction for combining a map $B_1\rightarrow A$ and $B_2\rightarrow A$ to get a map $B_1\times B_2\rightarrow A$. (Instead, we get a map from the *disjoint union* of $B_1$ and $B_2$ to $A$; the category theoretic terminology is "coproduct.") So the "out-of" and "into" situations don't match.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes that is close to what I'm asking, but with $Y$ being a single space rather than a product of spaces. Is there space such that $\prod X_i \rightarrow Y$ can be written as a single space, let's say U. That is, the above is equivalent to $U \rightarrow Y$.

Comment: @CBBAM See my second comment - even for products of two sets, there's no general way to do this.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even before we ask about continuity, we have to ask about function formation in the first place. Here we run into trouble: there is in general no way to combine functions from a bunch of factor spaces into some common space into a single function from the product space into that same common space. And this is just a fact about sets:

> There is no obvious way in general to combine a map $f: A_1\rightarrow B$ and a map $g: A_2\rightarrow B$ into a map from $A_1\times A_2$ to $B$.

(By contrast, the "into the product" version is easy: given $f:B\rightarrow A_1$ and $g:B\rightarrow A_2$, consider the map $B\rightarrow A_1\times A_2: b\mapsto (f(b), g(b))$.)

Instead, what we get is a map from the **(disjoint) union** of $A_1$ and $A_2$ to $B$, given by

$$h(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x) & \mbox{ if }x\in A_1,\\
g(x) & \mbox{ if }x\in A_2.\\
\end{cases}$$

*(If $A_1$ and $A_2$ aren't disjoint, we need to "disjointify" them - e.g. replace $A_1$ by $A_1\times\{1\}$ and $A_2$ by $A_2\times\{2\}$.)*

---

This may seem weirdly asymmetric, but in fact there *is* a symmetry here, it's just harder to see. The operations of disjoint union and Cartesian product are in a sense "dual" to each other:

- The key feature of the Cartesian product $S\times T$ of sets $S$ and $T$ is that there are maps $\pi_S:S\times T\rightarrow S$ and $\pi_T: S\times T\rightarrow T$ (the **coordinate projection maps**) such that for every set $U$ and every pair of maps $f_S:U\rightarrow S$ and $f_T: U\rightarrow T$, there is **exactly one** map $h: U\rightarrow S\times T$ such that $f_S=\pi_S\circ h$ and $f_T=\pi_T\circ h$. Specifically, $h$ is just $$u\mapsto (f_S(u), f_T(u)).$$ In a sense, the Cartesian product of two sets maps to both the factor sets in a "universal" way.
- The dual situation holds for disjoint unions! Specifically, the key feature of the disjoint union $S\sqcup T$ is that we have maps $\iota_S: S\rightarrow S\sqcup T$ and $\iota_T: T\rightarrow S\sqcup T$ (the **inclusion maps**) such that for any other set $U$ and any pair of maps $f_S: S\rightarrow U$ and $f_T: T\rightarrow U$ there is exactly one map $h: S\sqcup T\rightarrow U$ such that $f_S=h\circ \iota_S$ and $f_T=h\circ \iota_T$. Specifically, this is the map $$x\mapsto\begin{cases}
  f_S(x) & \mbox{ if } x\in S,\\
  f_T(x) & \mbox{ if } x\in T.\\
  \end{cases}$$

  Why is this "dual" to the picture for the Cartesian product? Well, first of all note the arrow reversal: the $\pi$-maps were from the product to the factors, while the $\iota$-maps are from the "base sets" to their union, and we're considering maps *from* those "base sets" rather than *to* those base sets - and correspondingly, we have "mirrored compositions" ($\pi_S\circ h$ and $\pi_T\circ h$ versus $h\circ\iota_S$ and $h\circ\iota_T$). Basically, when we think in terms of abstract behavior of functions, the disjoint union is a "flipped around" version of the Cartesian product - even though they are in many ways totally different (e.g. consider their respective cardinalities)!

This may feel weird and wishy-washy at first, but in fact it's a first step along the road to **category theory**. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)#Definition) for some more details.

(And note that none of the above is about topological spaces specifically - already things are complicated just considering sets on their own!)

Comment: I very much thank you for the detailed reply. This is very interesting and I have actually been interested in learning some category theory as I am beginning to see it come up often. I have another, slightly related, question while we're on the topics of continuous functions and products. I know in general the box topology fails continuity, but is there any condition in which it holds?

Comment: @CBBAM What do you mean by "in general the box topology fails continuity"?

Comment: As in the set of continuous functions from $X \rightarrow \prod Y_i$ is the same as the product of the set of continuous functions $X \rightarrow Y_i$. I know the product topology preserves this, but I am wondering if anything similar can be said about the box topology.